# Getting the content of a paragraph

Tags: php

I want something like this

```
<p id="potato">Here's some text</p>

<?php
SomeSortOfCodeToGetTheContentOfParagraph(#potato)
$value = TheOutPutOfTheCodeAbove
?>
```

So basically I want a code that gets the content of the paragraph with ID `potato` and makes `$value` equal to that

I read something about DOM but I don't really understand that

It doesn't have to be a PHP code, as long as `$value` **is** PHP and can be defined that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server side language, that means all the code you write evaluates before generating the DOM, you can't manipulate DOM like you want after it has been rendered. To do that you need to use javascript which is executed on the DOM, with php you can't basically do what you're trying to achieve, what you can do is retrieve the text with JS and pass it to PHP with GET or POST methods.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would achieve this. You could use:

```
$('#potato').text();
```

You should read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) to get a better grasp of how you can use it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `DOMDocument` class in PHP. Although I'm not sure where you're getting that string from, a quick mockup would be:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<p id="potato">Here\'s some text</p>');
foreach($doc->childNodes as $item):
    if($item->nodeType == 1):
        echo $item->nodeValue;
    endif;
endforeach;
```